# How can you use Apache .htaccess to specify the location of the PHP binary on shared hosting?

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, apache2

I'm using shared hosting, can create `.htaccess` and `php.ini` and have access to ssh.
I have PHP 5.6 installed to `~/public_html/php56` and can use this path with `ssh`, `cron` and `exec()` but not on the web.
Apache uses php 5.4 because it's set in `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
```

Is it possible to specify full php path using maybe AddHandler, Action, CGI etc.?

Comment: Are you on a shared host? If so, you can't the PHP version you're running.

Comment: I can choose it by defining `AddHandler` application/x-httpd-php54\53\52 etc. but it uses root php installs

Comment: I used to be a web host and I can tell you that unless it is installed for global use, more than likely not. You would/may need access to files and directories that effect other sites and that would not be allowed for safety sake. Web hosts do not like single sites negatively effecting other sites.

Comment: @JohnConde It is possible. I am a web host and my customers can change their PHP version (e.g. PHP 5.3 or 5.4)

Comment: Can your customers define full PHP path in .htaccess?

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards Admittedly, things have changed, but in the commercial world, servers were highly locked down for reasons of protection. I even went as far as disabling un-safe script installs automatically and no user had enough privs to install much beyond that. There would be one version of anything and that was the fully tested sanctioned and safe (assumed safe) version. Even e-mails were scrubbed, poked, prodded, inspected, and required to salute. But like I said, that was a decade ago. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Doing it through a .htaccess file while theoretically possible can cause issues and so many shared web hosts prevent that directive in .htaccess. However depending on the hosting panel they are using you may be able to specify the PHP version to use using the hosting panel itself. Both cPanel and Plesk have the ability to specify the PHP version to be used for the websites on the account.